# What chemical is responsible for the distinictive odor of Scotch tape?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, smell

[Scotch Tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_Tape) has a distinctive odor which is noticeable if you hold a piece close enough to smell. What chemical is responsible for this odor? The wikipedia page doesn't seem to mention composition.

Is the odor due to the the kind of plastic used in the strip of tape itself? Or is it due to the adhesive?

Comment: You might be smelling ozone and nitrogen oxides created during ESD by pulling the tape off the roll. See http://www.adhesivesmag.com/articles/86652-protecting-adhesive-tape-systems-from-static-electricity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long answer, but according to [this](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-1/Cellophane-Tape.html):

> While some pressure sensitive tapes are still prepared with natural
>   rubber, the majority are now made using mostly synthetic materials.
>   The backing for cellophane tape usually consists of cellulose acetate,
>   a synthetic derivative of cellulose, which comes from wood pulp or
>   cotton seeds. The cellulose is chemically treated with acetic acid and
>   anhydride, and the side that won't receive an adhesive coating is
>   treated with a release agent that enables the tape to be wound and
>   unwound without sticking together. Although this compound varies among
>   manufacturers, some commonly used substances include stearato chromic
>   chloride and polystearic carbonate. Prior to the application of the
>   adhesive, the adherend side of the backing may be primed with a
>   solvent or aqueous dispersions such as nitrile rubber or chlorinated
>   rubber. To produce the final adhesive substance, some manufacturers
>   use as many as 29 raw materials that go through various stages of
>   production. However, the generic adherend is made up of acrylic
>   resins, petroleum byproducts that are broken down into alcohols and
>   acids before being fused into a polymer compound. This compound is
>   then mixed with mineral spirits or a hydrocarbon solvent, creating an
>   aqueous emulsion (a solution in which the microscopic resin particles
>   are held suspended) that is applied to the backing.

In other word, there are many candidates.  I consider the top possibilities of those listed above to be: compounds composing the cellulose, the nitrile-based rubber compounds, and the semi-volatile organics composing both the adhereant and the base material.  With so many compounds going into a single product, it is likely the mixture that gives the distinctive smell rather than any individual compound.